# Chrome -webkit-object-fit doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, css

Using `-webkit-object-fit` in stylesheet in Chrome generates "unknown property name".

Is it just not supported? `-webkit-border-image` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/object-fit

**Updated Feb 15, 2016**

This extension is now supported without prefixes in all major browsers except Internet Explorer and Edge (although it is [flagged as Under Consideration](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectposition/) with medium priority in Edge, so it is likely to be supported there in the future).

**Original (outdated) answer**

> This particular extension appears to be an Opera-backed project, as it
>   has not garnered support from any other browsers.

Comment: oh good to know. It's a good image resize tool. Do you have any suggestion for alternatives? Thanks.

Comment: I found this blog post about [Maintaining Aspect Ratio When Adjusting Height or Width](http://addedoptimization.com/css-styling-image-height-and-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio/) a while ago... but I admit I have never tried using it.

Comment: @SeanXiao: In case of you are still looking for alternate solution for object-fit, refer to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21355203/140693

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no active webkit-based browser that supports the object-fit property. This property has been around for quite a while, and the spec reached candidate recommendation because it was implemented in Opera Presto (<= 12) browsers and the HP TouchPad (WebOS 3.0). However, both of these are obsolete and so the property appears in the [CSS Images Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-4/#the-object-fit) spec too

It has since been added to Chrome 32, though as this uses Blink, the property is unprefixed, so there's no need to use the -webkit- prefix.

If you're looking for a polyfill, I've made a jQuery based one, which you can get at http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2012/css3-object-fit-polyfill/