# Vertically center image on page and maintain aspect ratio on resize

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to do the following...

1. Have an image that will always be horizontally and vertically centered on a page, whatever the screen size.
2. Maintain aspect ratio on resize
3. Have some text that will always be at the bottom of the viewport.

I have come up with two half solutions so far...

- Solution 1 - http://jsfiddle.net/5jphd/ - This works but does not maintain aspect ratio
- Solution 2 - http://jsfiddle.net/FAzBq/ - This is not vertically centered.

I am looking for a solution that combines both the above. Here is my code if you can't click the links above...

HTML

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="text">Scroll down</div>
```

CSS

```
//Solution 1

html, body {height: 100%}

body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;      
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.text {
    margin-top: -50px;
    text-align: center;     
}

// Solution 2 - same as above but with .wrap class

.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 65%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the image is big enough, you can use `max-width` and `max-height` instead of `width` and `height`. This will reduce the size of the image as necessary,  maintaining the aspect ratio.

```css
img {
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: 70%;
}
```

To center it, you can use the absolute centering technique...

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body, .image, .wrap {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.text {
  margin-top: -50px;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text">Scroll down</div>
```

... or the similar fixed centering technique.

```css
img {
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.text {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text">Scroll down</div>
```

However, note that using `max-width` and `max-height` won't increase the size of the image to fill a bigger screen. This may be a good thing, because it won't become blurred.

But if you want it to fill the screen, even if the image is smaller, you can use [`object-fit: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

```css
img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
.text {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text">Scroll down</div>
```

Note IE does not support `object-fit` yet.

Comment: There are polyfills for `object-fit`, like [object-fit-images](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/), that add support to IE