# How do you keep the height relative to the width for a slideshow (w/ images)

Tags: html, css

Full code can be seen [here](http://github.com/judgemadan/isbhstechwebsite)

Since I am a new stackoverflow user and I can't post images, I will be posting my problem w/ images to make it more clear in a google doc.
[Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1egFD_08d1piO-bnrbbUyRl-Tt9IerxbsGxwfM5SOGPA/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly, but I made an fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/bocb1eod/

Comment: Are you allowed to use JavaScript?

Comment: use max-width / max-height to keep aspect ratio - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355111/vertically-center-image-on-page-and-maintain-aspect-ratio-on-resize

Comment: @schenck Yes I'm allowed to use JS

Comment: You could solve it with JS. However, if the CSS suggestions work I would rather use those.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

It is using background images and using `background-size: cover;` it preserves  the aspect ratio.