# Scale div so that it always keeps its aspect ratio and stays centered

Tags: html, image, css, aspect-ratio

My english is not good, so i can't explain well enough, but here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/lucifer63/qugph22u/) [404]

In the example if you resize window, the background image of `div.main` always will be sized in accordance with its ratio (1280*752).
It would be perfect if I knew how to make div be resize the same way as its background.

There is almost the same thing in this question - [Vertically center image on page and maintain aspect ratio on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355111/), but:
1. I want `<div>` to be flexible, not `<img>`,
2. In the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355111/#answer-21355203) you can see that actual image really keeps ratio, but `<img>` container itself does not.

Is there a way to make `<div>` keep the aspect ratio of an image only with CSS? No matter if it's a background image or a separate`<img>`?

HTML5, CSS3 methods are preferred

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/63aKp/87/?

Comment: To always keep the image aspect ratio, make sure only **either** `width` **or** `height` is set. The browser then does calculate the other part, maintaining the correct aspect ratio automatically.

For other html elements, a pure CSS solution that behaves identically is not possible imho.

Comment: web-tiki, yes, like this, but i need `<div>` to keep ratio of an image, not 1:1

Comment: ok @lucifer63, like this then http://jsfiddle.net/63aKp/127/ ?

Comment: wow, 100vw and 100vh works awesome, but can you please edit your fiddle so that img was inside div and i could add elements into div without additional positioning? I want `<img>` to be a background for `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        adjustDivHeight();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustDivHeight();
        });
    });

    function adjustDivHeight() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var width = $('#div_container_adjustable').width();
            var height = width * 0.5589123;
            $('#div_container_adjustable').height(height);
        }, 300);
    }
</script>
<div id="div_container_adjustable" class="detail_image"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't find CSS solution for my problem, so despite i wanted only CSS, i'll use JS solution)

Answer (score 2):

You need to try and compensate for the height.

to do this we need a padding percentage so we dived the `width` of your `image` by its height and that gives you 0.5875 so that means or padding should be 58.75%

make sure its a block element so that the `<div>` width can stretch right out.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
}
.yourdiv {
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding-top: 58.75%;
  background-image: url("http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2013/297/4/8/conquistadors_ii_by_shutupandwhisper-d6ro3z5.jpg");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  /* for show */
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="yourdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. In your solution background image is slightly zoomed when window is wider than max-width of `.yourdiv`, 2. `.yourdiv` isn't keeping vertical ratio(

Comment: updating it try with this  background-size:100% auto;
  background-position:top left; or keep center

Comment: Man, look at my example - http://jsfiddle.net/lucifer63/qugph22u/ )) It shows exactly what i want to achieve but with div, not div's background

Comment: That is exactly what the div is doing. the div is keeping aspect ratio.

Comment: When i open your snippet in fullscreen, i see that div is not keeping ratio of background image

Comment: yes because its not inside a wrapper of any sort. updated it to show you an example of how it would behave in a div.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a pseudo-element and vertical padding to keep the ratio width/height of a box based only on its width.

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  }
div {
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  border:solid;
  }
div:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block; 
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top:60%;
  }
```

```html
<div>boxe, resize window's width</div>
```

for the vertical position of the box, you an use either the flex model or table-layout or  a [pseudo element and inline-block properties](http://jsfiddle.net/qugph22u/4/). There is also the absolute and negative margin or translate technic.