# How to shrink divs vertically while keeping aspect ratio and location relative to other divs?

Tags: html, css, resize, viewport, responsive

In **HTML** images tend to keep their aspect ratio by default, which makes it easy to shrink images horizontally and keep proportions when the window is resized like this:

[image]

In the gif notice how the images not only keep aspect ratio but they stay together. They don't just get smaller in their own containers. This is what I want to accomplish, but vertically. ( When the window is dragged from bottom to top ).

All of the code to this simple demo is below. Currently if you make the snippet full screen and shrink the window vertically everything just gets clipped like this:

[image]

I want to keep everything on screen just like when it scales horizontally. I want it to behave in exactly the same way, but when the window is scaled *vertically*.

I've tried giving every element a width of `auto` or giving it a value of `display: inline-block`. Any ideas?

```css
/* //////////////////////////// IMPORTS ////////////////////////// */
@import url( "https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css" );

/* //////////////////////////// INITIAL ////////////////////////// */
body {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
img, footer {
  width: 100%;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.img-contr {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
}

/* /////////////////////////// CORE CLASSES ////////////////////// */
.clr-fix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.v-cntr {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * { 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        outline: 1px solid #f00;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="v-cntr">

  <!-- -------------------------- HEADER ------------------------ -->
  <header>
    <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/xH.svg" 
         alt="blue old fashioned car"
    >
  </header>

  <!-- --------------------------- MAIN ------------------------- -->
  <main class="clr-fix">
    <div class="img-contr">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/xe.svg" alt="car key">
    </div>
    <div class="img-contr">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/wz.svg" alt="seat belt">
    </div>
    <div class="img-contr">
      <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/vu.svg" alt="car pedals">
    </div>
  </main>

  <!-- -------------------------- FOOTER ------------------------ -->
  <footer>
    <p>footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**EDIT** So I a made gif showing exactly what I want to accomplish. But I made it by screenshotting my website and making the whole thing an image. The goal is to do this with multiple images inside divs like inside my code. Here is what I want to accomplish:

[image]

This question: [Vertically center image on page and maintain aspect ratio on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355111/vertically-center-image-on-page-and-maintain-aspect-ratio-on-resize)
is a solution for one image. When I try it in my code the images scale but they separate. Setting every image to `max-height: 100%` doesn't solve at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically center image on page and maintain aspect ratio on resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355111/vertically-center-image-on-page-and-maintain-aspect-ratio-on-resize)

Comment: @ZachSaucier If I apply `max-height: 100%` on all my images like the solution for that answer suggests it has a completely different affect on my layout than what I'm showing here due to the div containers. Sadly I don't think that solution will work.

Comment: Size the child elements in respect to the parent

Comment: You can use one of the approaches in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/scaling-responsive-animations/) to get the effect you're looking for

Comment: Can you use flexbox? Do `<header>` and `.img-contr` have set heights? For example they have set widths 100% and 33% respectively.

Comment: @joshhunt Flexbox is fine and the containers do not have set heights. I only want to keep the aspect ratios of all the content as it scales.

Comment: They don't have to have set heights. I would like them to be 3 columns in a row as in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So with the help of `vmin` units and [aspect ratio media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) I was able to put together something that reflects what works best for me as a solution to this question:

```css
/* ///////////////////////////////// IMPORTS /////////////////////////////// */
@import url( "https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css" );

/* ///////////////////////////////// INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
html, body {
  padding: 0.5%;
}
body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
body, .top-contr {
  margin: auto;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
}

/* ///////////////////////////////// STRUCTURE ///////////////////////////// */

/* / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / HEADER / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
header, footer, main .top-contr {
  padding: 1%;
}
header .top-contr {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 15%;
}
.top-contr, .v-cntr, .v-cntr-a {
  position: relative;
}
.cnt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / MAIN / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
main .top-contr {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
}
main .mid-contr {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 45%;
}
main .cnt {
  padding: 4%;
}

/* / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / FOOTER / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
footer .top-contr {
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 5%;
}

/* //////////////////////////////// CORE CLASSES /////////////////////////// */
.clr-fix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.v-cntr {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}

/* /////////////////////////////// MEDIA QUERIES /////////////////////////// */
@media ( min-aspect-ratio: 3/2 ) {
  body {
    width: 135vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
  }
}
@media ( min-aspect-ratio: 3/2 ) and ( min-width: 1000px ) {
  .v-cntr-a {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY( -50% );
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="v-cntr">                  <!-- << v-cntr = vertically center -->
  <div class="wrapper v-cntr-a">
  
    <!-- ----------------------------- HEADER --------------------------- -->
    <header>
      <div class="top-contr">                   <!-- << contr = container -->
        <div class="cnt">                           <!-- << cnt = content -->
          <p class="v-cntr">header</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- ------------------------------ MAIN ---------------------------- -->
    <main>
      <div class="top-contr">
        <div class="mid-contr">
          <div class="cnt">
            <p class="v-cntr">rectangle 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="top-contr">
        <div class="mid-contr">
          <div class="cnt">
            <p class="v-cntr">rectangle 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="top-contr">
        <div class="mid-contr">
          <div class="cnt">
            <p class="v-cntr">rectangle 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- ----------------------------- FOOTER --------------------------- -->
    <footer>
      <div class="top-contr">
        <div class="cnt">
          <p class="v-cntr">footer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Aslo see accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757168/how-to-keep-aspect-ratio-on-a-vertically-scaling-div-not-image?noredirect=1&lq=1