# alternative to object-fit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. I´m looking for an alternative to css object-fit property for Firefox and IE.The Property works well in Chrome and Opera but not in Firefox and IE.
2. I tried the imgLiquid Plugin but the image does not appear when the image source will be changed . (the images will be loaded every second from a web camera)

Is there any solution or alternative for 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/object-fit

This particular extension appears to be an Opera-backed project, as it has not garnered support from any other browsers.

**Source:** [Chrome -webkit-object-fit doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128377/chrome-webkit-object-fit-doesnt-work)